# CSS Animation not working

Tags: html, css, animation

Here is the code, I really dont understand what is wrong.

I also tried using -webkit- but did not make any difference trying to move the objects accross the screen, simple animation

HTML:

```
<body>

    <h1 class='cloud'>
    SKILLS
    </h1>

    <h1 class='balloon'>
    WORKS
    </h1>

</body>
```

CSS:

```
    .cloud  {
       background: url(../image/cloudskills.svg)no-repeat;
       height:100px;
       width:130px;
       text-indent: -999em;
       animation: cloud 5s linear infinite;
       -webkit-animation: cloud 5s linear infinite;
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes cloud {
       0%, 100% {
       left: 0%;
     }
       50% {
       left: 100%;
     }
   }

   .balloon {
     background: url(../image/balloonworks.svg)no-repeat;
     width: 100px;
     height: 130px;
     text-indent: -999em;
     animation: balloon 5s linear infinite;
   }

   @keyframes balloon{
     0%, 100% {
      left: 0%;
     }
     50% {
      left: 100%;
     }
   }
```

Comment: remove `enter code here` from your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/m0euady9/)

for the elements to make some animation `position` should be given so `aboslute` or `relative` or you can use `margin` in keyframes to move the element

```
.cloud {
    background: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/8800.png)no-repeat;
    height:100px;
    width:130px;
    background-size:100px auto;
    text-indent: -999em;
    animation: cloud 5s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: cloud 5s linear infinite;
    position:relative;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cloud {
    0%, 100% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    50% {
        left: 100%;
    }
}
.balloon {
    background: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/8800.png)no-repeat;
    background-size:100px auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 130px;
    text-indent: -999em;
    animation: cloud 5s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation: cloud 5s linear infinite;
    position:relative;
}
@-webkit-keyframes balloon {
    0%, 100% {
        left: 0%;
    }
    50% {
        left: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed only a bit of your code http://jsfiddle.net/2gbngtxp/

```
@-webkit-keyframes cloud {
   0% {
   left: 0;
 }
   50% {
   margin-left: 100%; /*changed 'left:100%' to 'margin-left:100%'*/
 }
100%{
    left:0;
}
```